# TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined in $http.get(...).sucess function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, router

I have this login function with an `$http.get`. I am trying to get the view to change in case I get a success.

The user should click login and it will call `submitLogin()` who should check with the server, who should send back a JSON with "`success`" plus some data.

I am trying to get the view to change if the login is successful but I cant seem to get it right, even though `$location` is injected in my function definition I still get the following error:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

Here is my controller code. Is it possible to change the path in the success callback? Should I do it in another way?

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module('loginPage', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:'html/login.html',
            controller: 'testController'
                  })
        .when('/EventList',{templateUrl:'html/eventList.html'})
        .when('/EventDetail',{templateUrl:'html/eventDetail.html'})
        .when('/GroupDetail',{templateUrl:'html/workGroupDetail.html'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
    }]);

    app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
       var eventList = this, 
           event = {};
       eventList.events = [];
       $scope.submitLogin = function () {
           var promise = $http.get('../json/Login.json');
           promise.then(function (response) {
               if (response.data.success) {
                   $location.path("/EventList");
                   eventList.events = response.data.eventHead;
               } else {
                   window.alert("nosuccess");
               }
           }, function (error) {
               window.alert('Error' + error);
           });
       };
    }]);
   }());
```

Comment: Try $window.location.path